# Требования к хостингу для 1C битрикс

Tags: веб-программирование, битрикс, 1с

Какой нужен хостинг  для 1C битрикс?

Comment: Ответ в документации к 1С-Битрикс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Документация: [Хостинг для продуктов «1С-Битрикс»](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/partners/hosting.php#tab-virt-link)

> Для размещения сайтов на платформе «1С-Битрикс» **подходит любой
>   хостинг, который соответствует техническим требованиям продукта**.

Документация: [Минимальные технические требования](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/requirements.php#tab-min-link)

> - PHP 5.3 и выше
> - Apache 1.3 и выше
> - MySQL 5.0 и выше

Документация: [Тестирование хостинга](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/requirements.php#tab-hosting-link)

> ***Протестировать хостинг*** на предмет соответствия техническим требованиям продукта можно специальным скриптом:
>   [bitrix_server_test.php](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/bitrix_server_test.php). Загрузите его на хостинг, затем откройте в
>   браузере и нажмите кнопку «Начать тестирование».